# How to publish my web site using visual studio professional edition 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to publish my website using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
In my PC i am getting the following screen with the following steps,Build->Publish WebSite[image]

Attached Screenshot above"Publish Web"
[image]
But when i try to publish my website in my colleague PC i am getting the following screen

Attached screenshot above "Publish Web Site".
What is the difference between these two?How to get the "Publish Web Site" type of screen in my PC instead of "Publish Web" screen.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Install web matrix on your colleagues computer and try

Comment: I don't want to change anything in my colleague PC, i want Publish Web Site Screen (i.e., 2nd screenshot "Title as Publish Web Site") in my PC. can you help me?

Comment: Hi, Sorry what I meant was WebDeploy and not web matrix. The different publish screen you see on your collegues screen could be due to a missing plugin(or it could also  be due to the wrong type of solution, but I assume you would have made sure that its the same project type you are publishing). The screen on your computer is usually present on computers running visual studio along with Microsoft Web Platform installed. I am not 100% sure but I am pretty confident that if you install "web deploy" on your collegues computer and restart VS 2012 u will a similar screen.

Comment: Hi acutally in my colleague PC, already Web Deployment Tool is installed as like that of my PC. What will be the issue?Do i need to install any other plugins?